# passportjs and angularjs routing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, passport.js, angular-routing

I have a really big problem that i don't know how to solve, I trying to implement login authentication using passportJS in MEAN project.
When I'm trying to implement the login - I get this error again and again:
[image]

And here is my code: **login.html**

```
<form method="post">
   <input class="form_input" name="email" type="text" id="login_userName" ng-model="user.userName">
   <input class="form_input" name="password" type="password" id="login_pass" ng-model="user.password">
  <button class="form_btn" type="submit" ng-click="loginForm(user)">login!</button>
   </form>
```

**client.js** - angular routing

```
SocialParking.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.loginForm = function(user){
       $http.post('/login', user).then(function (response) {
           alert("Success Login! " + response);
    });
   }
});
```

**route.js** - the login code is not reach to here!

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
});
```

**passportConfig.js**

```
    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({
            username: username.toLowerCase()
        }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false);

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false);

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Where have you serialized and deserialized user? Also, where are you initializing passport?

Comment: I have them both. The serialize/deserialize in passportConfig. The problem is that the code is not reach to the server side from the client route.